# Filter only relevant params from request.params

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing an asp.net server for some application.
One of the functionality of that apllication is to get an json object and to write it to file. (The json is given by jquery ajax). Well, to get the sended json I tried to use request.params, but than I found out that the params contain not just my little json object, but about 60 another irelevante (for me) keys and values.
Can I seperate somehow the "regular" data and the specific sended json?

Thanks a lot and sorry for the bad english.

Comment: You should show how you are sending data (query string, body, headers, etc.). But you may be looking for `Request.QueryString`

Comment: I'll see the queryString, thanks! The query is sending in jquery ajax $.ajax({type:post, url:..., data:{key:value, key:value...})